# NoSuchMethodError using Twilio IPMessaging

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, twilio

I'm trying to use Twilio IP Messaging in a simple Xamarin Android project, but unfortunately running into issues with the latest Nuget libraries: Twilio.Common (v. 0.3.4.2) and Twilio.IPMessaging (I tried both 0.15.0.4 and 0.15.0.6).

My setup is complicated by the fact that the online Xamarin samples are obsoleted within the recent library releases --- so instead of calling methods to Initialize the Twilio SDK, my code simply invokes  Twilio.IPMessaging.IPMessagingClient.Create.  The input parameters are a bit unclear, but reading elsewhere I'm trying to bind using a signature:

```
IPMessagingClient IPMessagingClient.create(
   Context context, 
   AccessManager accessManager, 
   IPMessagingClient.Properties clientProperties, 
   Constants.CallbackListener<IPMessagingClient> listener)
```

Invoking it this way, I invariably receive an error message: **`NoSuchMethodError`** with details:

`"no static method \"Lcom/twilio/ipmessaging/IPMessagingClient;.create(Landroid/content/Context;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lcom/twilio/ipmessaging/IPMessagingClient;\"`

Any ideas?  I like the idea of using Twilio, but between the outdated documentation and unfortunate crashes it's looking simpler to just implement messaging myself.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I'm facing the exact same issue

Comment: Same here. Twilio support suggested that IPMessaging is now deprecated (it never went beyond Beta) and we should move to Programmable Chat. Problem is, the new product doesn't have Xamarin support, and they can't provide an ETA.

Answer (score 1):

While I check nugets can you provide more insights

1. why IPMessagingClient.create(...) and not IPMessagingClient.Create(...)?
2. Is linker turned on? Turn it off please. Then check.

Signature is

public static IPMessagingClient Create (Context context, Object acess_manager, Object properties, Object listener);

Comment: I've turned off the linker and it fails anyway...
I'm using as parameters: context: `this` (my activity) // access_manager: `new AccessManager(currentActivity, mytoken, this)` (_this_ implements `AccessManager.IListener` // listener: `new CustomTwilioClientListener` (inherits from `ConstantsCallbackListener`). 
My guess is the 3rd parameter fails. In the nuget package there is no such class `Constants.CallbackListener` that takes a generic parameter like Constants.CallbackListener<IPMessagingClient>